# Not able to get changes in code without a maven build

Tags: java, maven

I am writing a main method in java. Inside the main method ,i am creating the instance of a class that is available as .class in the same project. (folder in which the .class is there is added as a class folder).I am not able to run this main method as java application because it is not build (maven build).

And even if i build ,it wont be a success because of the content in it.What to do?. Why is that i need to maven build for my new changes to have impact.

```
public void getTest(){


    TestPro testPro=new TestProImpl();



    SamplePro samplePro=new SampleProImpl();



}


public static void main(String[] args){

Test test=new Test();
test.getTest();

}
```

TestPro  and SamplePro classes are available as .class files in a folder (same maven module) and is added as a class folder.

Comment: Would help if you put in sample code and the way your maven project is steup.

Comment: try to build with the command prompt with the command `mvn -x clean build`

Answer (score 1):

I Guess - You are using `eclipse-Editor` then,

Right click on Maven project into Project-Explorer.

`Either` one of the way may work for you great,

```
1. Right-click on Project -> Maven -> Update Project
2. Project -> Clean.
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Addition to my above suggestion also try to change java code.

Comment: so that eclipse compiler again compiled changed/updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not an interpreted language like script languages, so the code (the .java file) needs to be compile into a .class file first because it can be run. If you are making a change in the .java file, this must also be reflected in the .class file, so you have to compile it.

Some IDEs (like Eclipse) provide functionality to automatically compile, once you save your file.

Comment: the .class files are generated. so there is no .java files

Comment: The code that you posted in your question is in the .java file. There is the possibility that in your maven project some code is generated (would still be .java files) that are then compiled. If that is the case, please mention the fact in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the problems listed in the problems window of Eclipse Editor solved my problem. Maven is asking to build again because of the existing problems within the project structure.Rectifying all the project structural changes have solve this issue for me.